# React-Native app doesn't work if i use await

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is the first time I'm using react-native to develop an Android app.
I'm trying to use async/await when I retrieve some data from `firestore`, but when I add the word await the app crashes and it won't start anymore.
I use `react-native-firebase` library as you can see in my package.json file.
**This is the part of my component that doesn't work:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getAccountFromFirestore(this.props.user);
}

getAccountFromFirestore = async user => {
  const accounts = await firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection('accounts')
   .get();

  this.setState({ loading: false }); 
};
```

**This is my package.json, if it's usefull**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.6",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.493",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: try using .then() promise

Comment: If you don't mind, please share your error's message (and preferably a stack trace) with us here.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement with Promise like :

```
 firebase
 .firestore()
 .collection('accounts')
  .get()
  .then(accounts => {
   console.log ('Use accounts variable as per your requirement,'accounts)
  })
  .catch(error => {console.error(error)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's your React Native or if you're using **Node 6**. But for what I know, `async/await` is **only supported** on **Node 8 or above**. So, your best bet is still using `Promises` with this problem. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getAccountFromFirestore(this.props.user);
}

getAccountFromFirestore = user => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('accounts')
    .get()
    .then(accounts => {
      let data = accounts.docs.map(account => account.data());
      console.log(data);

      this.setState({ loading: false });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Also when using `async/await`, don't forget the `try-catch` blocks:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getAccountFromFirestore(this.props.user);
}

getAccountFromFirestore = async user => {
  try {
    const accounts = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('accounts')
      .get();

    const data = accounts.docs.map(a => a.data());
    console.log(data);

    this.setState({ loading: false });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Option a) keep using promises
Option b) Migrate that RN, if you can use async/await your code is prob too old to go in the stores anyway.
Option c) Babel...